# IndexedDB - Duplicate database

Tags: ember.js, indexeddb

I am using indexedDB in emberjs with an Adapter ([Here](https://github.com/kurko/ember-indexeddb-adapter)) for that. It's working the same way as a normal implementation of indexedDB request, but every time I refresh my page twice, there is a new database created with the same name as the one I'm using.
When I clear the cache and cookie, I have to close and reopen chrome to actually refresh the indexedDB information.

After the clear cache, I run my page for the first time, it's working fine, I can see the data inside the chrome debugger. But when I reload twice, a new database with the same name as the one I'm using is created but without any table in it. And my first database is still there with my table, but I can't see the information in it.

When I refresh my page it's only callback onsuccess, not even onupgrade.

Is this a common bug of indexedDB ?

Comment: I think it is just usual dev panel bug.

Comment: I hope so, but for now it seems that I can still fetch the data from it. Not very easy to debug...